# videosdk library is opening back camera instead of front in iphone

Tags: jquery, video-streaming, video-library, videosdk.live, iphone-video

I am using videosdk for video meeting in my website. Everything is working fine on Android and desktop but while using iPhone, it starts back camera instead of front camera. However, I have used facing mode as front.

```
async function startMeeting(token, meetingId, name) {
   let customVideoTrack = await window.VideoSDK.createCameraVideoTrack({
      optimizationMode: "motion",
      encoderConfig: "h1080p_w1440p",//h540p_w960p
      facingMode: "front",
   });

   let customAudioTrack = await VideoSDK.createMicrophoneAudioTrack({
      encoderConfig: "high_quality",
      noiseConfig: {
          noiseSuppresion: true,
          echoCancellation: true,
          autoGainControl: true,
      },
   });
}
```

This is happening on both safari and chrome browser.